# Search module in html block

Tags: search

I am new expression engine..I have added a htmlblock widget to a page that would show search box but is not supporting the {exp:search:simple_form channel} all these tags what should i do?

Here is my code

```
{exp:search:simple_form channel="blog|news|pages" search_in="everywhere" where="all" result_page="search/" no_result_page="search/no_results" show_expired="yes" show_future_entries="yes"}
    <input type="text" name="keywords" id="keywords" value="" size="18" maxlength="100" />
    <input type="submit" value="" class="searchbtn" /> 
{/exp:search:simple_form}
```

Thanks, Neha

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have some form input elements within your simple_form tags you also need to include the results tags somewhere. Normally this is on another 'page' but I think you can do it on the same page.

Documentation for the results tags can be found at http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/modules/search/results.html

Basically, you do something like:

```
{exp:search:search_results}
    {title}
    {other_custom_field1}
    {other_custom_field2}
    etc...
{/exp:search:search_results}
```

Which will loop through the results and display any data you put within the loop for each result.

In light of your comment...

That's a huge question, another one!

I would suggest you take a look at http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/intro/the_big_picture.html to start with. Basically, the URLs used on your site map to your template groups and templates.  It's really fundamental that you understand how EE's templating works so I would go look at those docs before you go any further with your site otherwise I fear you will run into bigger problems further down the line.

So to make things simple, start by creating a template group named "search". Create a template in there called results - this is where you would use the tags I show above.

Then set your results_page parameter to point at "search/results".

Comment: Can you please tell how to use a particular template in a page??